# Issue with ie9 and compiled LESS CSS

Tags: html, css, less

This is the LESS CSS I'm currently using.

ie9 stops after this

```
#oo-terms, #oo-privacy, #fbpage, #termrewards, #panelerrorpage{
      #wrapper{
          height:100%;
          @media only screen and (max-width : 1020px) { width:95%; padding: 0 2.5%;}
          #content-wrapper{
              background:@light-grey;
              width:100%;
              max-width:1000px;
              margin-left:auto;
              margin-right:auto;
              -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #636363;
              -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #636363;
              box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #636363;
              -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
              -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
              border-radius: 0px;
              position:inherit;
              margin-top:30px;
              display:block;
              @media only screen and (max-width : 1020px) {width:95%; padding: 5% 2.5%; }
              #facebookRegister, #facebookThankYou{
                  padding: 2.5%;
                  width: 95%;
                  color:@dark-blue;
                  clear:both;
                  .welcome{color:@dark-blue;}
                  div{
                      color:@dark-blue !important;
                      position:inherit !important;
                      top:0px;
                      left:0px;
                      h2{color:@dark-blue !important;}
                  }
                  .facebook-login-button{
                                    width:280px;
                                    float:none;
                                    position:inherit;
                                    margin:0px;
                                    padding:0px;
                                    background:#3b5999;
                                    height:36px;
                                    -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
                                    -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
                                    border-radius: 0px;
                                    .facebook-login-mid{
                                        width:100%;
                                        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
                                        font-size:14px;
                                        line-height:36px;
                                        height:36px;
                                        -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
                                        -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
                                        border-radius: 0px;
                                        background:url('/App_Presentation/panel/OpinionOutpost/img/oo-new-fbbg.png') no-repeat;
                                        background-position: 6px 0px;
                                        a{
                                            width: 237px;
                                            padding: 0 0 0 35px;
                                            display: block;
                                            background: 0;
                                            text-align: center;
                                            cursor: pointer;
                                            height: 36px;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                  .left{
                      width:45%; 
                      margin-right:5%; 
                      float:left; 
                      margin-top:50px;
                      @media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {width:100%; float:none; margin-right:0px;}

                  }
                  .right{
                      width:46%; 
                      float:right; 
                      margin-top:50px;
                      @media only screen and (max-width : 700px) {width:100%; float:none; margin-right:0px;}
                      input{
                        width:216px;
                        padding:0 10px 0 10px;
                        -webkit-border-radius: 0px; 
                        -moz-border-radius: 0px; 
                        border-radius: 0px; 
                        border: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
                        height:36px;
                        line-height:36px;
                        color:#cdcdcd;
                        margin-top:10px;
                        font-weight:normal;
                        margin-left:0px;
                        }
                        label{
                            display:none;
                        }
                        #fbSyncAccount{
                            background:@light-blue;
                            margin: 10px auto;
                            border:none;
                            color:#ffffff;
                        }
                      }
                  .right:after{clear:both;}
              }

          }
      }
}
```

I do not see any issues with this css, I'm wondering if IE9 has any conflicts with any of these classes...

Heres the real kicker... IE8 continues reading the CSS til the bottom of the document.

Here is what comes after

```
#termrewards, #panelerrorpage{
    #content-wrapper{
        width:95%;
        padding:2.5%;
    }
}
input[type="text"], input[type="password"]{
    @media only screen and (max-width : 1024px) {font-size:16px !important; }
}
#rewardpage #wrapper #large-right p a{color:@light-blue;}
#modal-container .red-button-mid{background:@light-blue;}
#modal-container .red-button-mid:hover{background:@light-blue;}
.facebook-login-button{
    position:relative;
    img{
        position:absolute;
        right:6px;
        top:6px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pure guess, based on comment about IE8, but I would try commenting out the `@media` queries and see if it works. IE9 began to support those, IE8 did not. It could be IE8 is ignoring them, but for some reason IE9 is getting hung on them. I assume you are compiling client side with this, else IE9 would not even be reading the LESS code, but only the final precompiled CSS served up.

Comment: As a side note, that code produces some horrible selectors. `#panelerrorpage #wrapper #content-wrapper #facebookThankYou .right:after` is rather ridiculous. Sometimes it is best to know when not to nest selectors in LESS. I'm guessing all `#facebookThankYou`'s are inside `#wrapper` and `#content-wrapper`, so even reducing to `#panelerrorpage #facebookThankYou .right:after` would be better, but you might even be able to reduce to `#facebookThankYou .right:after` if there are no "exception" pages that it would be found on (that is, no need to define it explicitly for every page). My 2 cents.

Comment: One more thing, if IE9 stops "after" that code (but does read that code), you might want to post the LESS code that follows that code (the first part that does not get processed), as that may be where the error is.

Comment: @scottS touche, I've edited my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're dealing with a lot of selectors, you could be experiencing this:

> Internet Explorer 9 and below cannot process more than 4,095 selectors from a single CSS file. Any additional selectors are ignored.

Your solution could potentially be this: http://blesscss.com/

Comment: Thank you! I wish it hadn't taken me 4 days of slow debugging in BrowserStack and googling to realize this... g'damn.